# how to evaluate return is true or not in Aura Javascript

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

I have an Apex Method named "ShowOutput" which is returning either true or false.

How can I evaluate the response is true or not in Aura controller.

I tried below code

```
var action = component.get('c.showOutput');        
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state === 'SUCCESS') {
            component.set('v.searchHub', 'health-source');
        } else {
            component.set('v.source', 'health-source1');
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**getReturnValue()**

Gets the return value of an Apex action. An Apex action can return any object containing serializable JSON data.

> check this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_jsapi_action.htm) for more methods on **reponse** Obejct

you can use `response.getReturnValue()` to see if you apex class returned **True** or **false** considering your apex class returns **Boolean** value

Example

```
var action = component.get('c.showOutput');
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if(state === 'SUCCESS') {
        var result = response.getReturnValue(); //value returned from your apex class
        if(result) {
            component.set('v.searchHub', 'health-source');
        } else {
            component.set('v.source', 'health-source1');
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Error: ' + response.getError());
    }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Comment: thanks Aman, it worked